# Using if statement in erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement, erb

I am new on ruby on rails and working on a sample project to build a forum. I try to set a super admin which could delete other admins. But always cannot pass the spec.

Here is my code
views/user/_user.html.erb

```
<li>
<%= gravatar_for user, size: 52 %>
<%= link_to user.name, user %>
<% if (current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) && !user.admin?) ||  current_user.sadmin? %>
| <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete,
                data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
<% end %>
</li>
```

spec/requests/user_page_spec

```
 describe "delete links" do

  it { should_not have_link('delete') }

  describe "as an admin user" do
    let(:admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:admin) }
    before do
      sign_in admin
      visit users_path
    end

    it { should have_link('delete', href: user_path(User.first)) }
    it "should be able to delete another user" do
      expect do
        click_link('delete', match: :first)
      end.to change(User, :count).by(-1)
    end
    it { should_not have_link('delete', href: user_path(admin)) }
  end

  describe "as an sadmin user" do
    let(:sadmin) { FactoryGirl.create(:sadmin) }
    let(:admin) {FactoryGirl.create(:admin)}
    before do
      sign_in sadmin
      visit users_path
    end

    it { should have_link('delete', href: user_path(User.first)) }
    it "should be able to delete another user" do
      expect do
        click_link('delete', match: :first)
      end.to change(User, :count).by(-1)
    end
    it { should have_link('delete', href: user_path(admin))}
    it { should_not have_link('delete', href: user_path(sadmin)) }
  end
end
end
```

when I try to run the spec the error is

```
 1) User pages index delete links as an sadmin user
     Failure/Error: it { should_not have_link('delete', href: user_path(sadmin)) }
       expected #has_link?("delete", {:href=>"/users/422"}) to return false, got true
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:66:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) User pages index delete links as an sadmin user
     Failure/Error: it { should have_link('delete', href: user_path(admin))}
       expected #has_link?("delete", {:href=>"/users/423"}) to return true, got false
   # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:65:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I am not sure if it means the syntax I use in erb file is wrong or some other things I messed up? Thanks in advance

Comment: No, syntax is fine. `Failure` means the expectation in your test was not met, not that the code failed to execute. What happens when you call `admin?` on the `sadmin` user? Is it `true` or `false`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In

```
    <% if (current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) && !user.admin?) ||  current_user.sadmin? %>
        | <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete,
                data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
    <% end %>
```

, it mean if "**current_user.sadmin?** " is true, the link will be displayed no matter other conditions. So ther is the failure

```
Failure/Error: it { should_not have_link('delete', href: user_path(sadmin)) }
       expected #has_link?("delete", {:href=>"/users/422"}) to return false, got true
```

I guess

```
it { should have_link('delete', href: user_path(admin))}
```

failed, is becuase the admin user has been deleted in

```
it "should be able to delete another user" do
      expect do
        click_link('delete', match: :first)
      end.to change(User, :count).by(-1)
    end
```

part?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your kind reply, I've fixed that bug, something wrong with other files... Thanks all the same!